# Converting seconds to Datetime in mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp, datetime, servlets

I am using JSP Servlets and have made a MySQL connection.
I have a value in seconds, which is basically the value of validity of a token.

I now want to convert this value and insert in Datetime format in MySQL.

So, bascially it should be something  like

Datetime( Current Time + expiry_value_in_seconds )

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *convert this value to Datetime format in MySQL.* Do you want to do it in query or JAVA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FoggyDay already answered how you can do it in Java, so I'll answer how to do it in MySQL specific SQL itself:

```
ADDDATE(current_timestamp, INTERVAL 10 second)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on the Java side, I'd use Calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, expiry_value_in_seconds);
```

Here is a great tutorial:

[Lars Vogel: 
Java Date, Calendar and Time APIs](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html)

Otherwise, I'd use mySql DATE_ADD():

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
- http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/DATEADDcurdateINTERVAL1SECOND.htm